# Get values from checkboxes in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a list of multiple strings. I want the user to choose one or more of these strings through a GUI interface. For example, if my list is `l = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog"]`, I want the GUI to show

```
□ apple
□ ball 
□ cat 
□ dog
```

I also want to read the inputs given by the user.
How can I generate checkboxes for each of these strings dynamically and read the inputs given by the user using tkinter?

Comment: What have you tried and what is the problem you came across?

Comment: I got how to instantiate checkboxes dynamically, but I don't understand how to retrieve user inputs

Comment: You need to associate an instance of tkinter variable, for example `IntVar()` or `StringVar()`, to each checkbox and store them in a list/dictionary. Then you can go through the list/dictionary to check which checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
window.title('My Window')
window.geometry('100x200')
 
def on_click():
    lst = [l[i] for i, chk in enumerate(chks) if chk.get()]
    print(",".join(lst))    
 
l = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog"]

chks = [tk.BooleanVar() for i in l]

for i, s in enumerate(l):
    tk.Checkbutton(window, text=s, variable=chks[i]).pack(anchor=tk.W)

tk.Button(window, text="submit", command=on_click).pack()
     
  
window.mainloop()
```

Result output:

[image]